# Java how to set 2011-11-06T14:34:16.679+02:00 into XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date

im building JAXWS client , one of the methods get XMLGregorianCalendar . 
now i need to format this data `2011-11-06T14:34:16.679+02:00` to be set into   XMLGregorianCalendar. how can it be done .
the date is taken from sniffing other clients that connecting to the WS server .

Comment: How to get the date in this format "2011-11-06T14:34:16.679+02:00" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date string into an java.util.Date object using follow method:

```
String strDate = "2011-11-06T14:34:16.679+02:00";
strDate = strDate.substring(0, 26) + strDate.substring(27, 29);

String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ";
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

Date d = sdFormat.parse(strDate);
```

Then set this Date into your XMLGregorianCalendarj

Comment: hi, how to get the date in this format "2011-11-06T14:34:16.679+02:00" ?